# Find Max and Min of Double Linked List in Golang

Tags: list, go, max, min, doubly-linked-list

I need to find a function where I get the max and min value (using int values) of a Double Linked List (not an array) using Golang. I've write the code for getting this values for array but i have no idea where to start when i use a double linked list (or circular) :

package main

import "fmt"

func main() {

```
var a = [5]int{11, -4, 7, 8, -10}
min, max := findMinAndMax(a)
fmt.Println("Min: ", min)
fmt.Println("Max: ", max)
```

}

This works but i need to replace the array with a double list (for ex. called 'l') where i have 5 int values (2,5,7,9,12) and i need to get the max and min values

```
 l={2,5,7,9,12} // Created a double linked list
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code will help you to find the answer. I used Go `container/list` package's (double) list to `findMinAndMax` operation.

```
package main

import (
    "container/list"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var a = [5]int{11, -4, 7, 8, -10}
    
    //declare a double list
    i := list.New()
    
    // push a's values to list
    for _, valueA := range a {
        i.PushFront(valueA)
    }
    
    min, max := findMinAndMax(i)
    fmt.Println("Min: ", min) //Output: Min:  -10
    fmt.Println("Max: ", max) //Output: Max:  11
}

func findMinAndMax(a *list.List) (min int, max int) {
    min = a.Front().Value.(int)
    max = a.Front().Value.(int)
    for e := a.Front(); e != nil; e = e.Next() {
        value := e.Value.(int)
        if value < min {
            min = value
        }
        if value > max {
            max = value
        }
    }
    return min, max
}
```

[The Go Playground for list](https://play.golang.org/p/JMTFVjFLDTB)

For circular linked list (ring) implementation will be as below. I used Go `container/ring` package's Ring for the implementation.

```
package main

import (
    "container/ring"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var a = [5]int{11, -4, 7, 8, -10}

    //declare a container ring
    r := ring.New(len(a))

    // push a's values to ring
    for _, valueA := range a {
        r.Value = valueA
        r = r.Next()
    }

    min, max := findMinAndMax(r)
    fmt.Println("Min: ", min) //Output: Min:  -10
    fmt.Println("Max: ", max) //Output: Max:  11
}

func findMinAndMax(r *ring.Ring) (min int, max int) {
    min = r.Value.(int)
    max = r.Value.(int)
    tmp := r
 
    for {
        value := r.Value.(int)
        if value < min {
            min = value
        }
        if value > max {
            max = value
        }
        r = r.Next()

        // r = tmp means one ring circle is completed
        if r == tmp {
            break
        }
    }
    return min, max
}
```

[The Go Playground for ring](https://play.golang.org/p/QKWZLNqQVP2)

Comment: Thank you very much nipuna!, i have a last question, how i could change this code to implement this max and min value into a double list but circular?

Comment: I have added the implementation for a ring into the answer.

Answer (score -1):

This was the code i've done for getting max and min of an arrau but i need both from a double linked list, hope this is understood:

```
func findMinAndMax(a [5]int) (min int, max int) {
min = a[0]
max = a[0]
for _, value := range a {
    if value < min {
        min = value
    }
    if value > max {
        max = value
    }
}
return min, max
```

}